# etomite: function eregi() deprecated ... but it isn't anywhere?

Tags: php, function, content-management-system

http://lubela.sk/index.php?id=122

Can anyone help me with this error? I have searched all the web files for "eregi" and it isn't really anywhere. So ... what's up with this error? :o

```
574 if(is_array($params)) {
575     extract($params, EXTR_SKIP);
576 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see here

```
/data/web/lubela.sk/web/index.php(576) : eval()'d code
```

it is propably not in your code as a concrete function call, but somewhere in a string, that you send to `eval`. "eval is evil" anyway ;)

Find out where the strings with the code at that line comes from and then you should know, where you have to look for `eregi`.

Comment: Where could it be coming from? SQL ? lol. I have searched using shell through ALL the web files, it isn't anywhere. I am going to try SQL ...

Comment: The string can come from everywhere. Look at `index.php:576`. There should be something like `eval($string)`. Then scroll up and search for that moment, where `$string` get its content.

Answer (score 1):

You could be hacked, since eval() is often used to unpack base64-encoded code, which can be in turn obfuscated with regular expressions and gz-compression instead of base64_decode()